# Can admin create files manually within C:\inetpub\wwwroot under Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows, security, iis, administrator

Is it possible for someone with Administrator access to easily create arbitrary files (e.g. text documents) within the C:\Inetpub\wwwroot folder under Windows 8.1?

Normally right-click presents me with many file types I can create; here, I'm only given the option to create a new sub-folder, even though I can (i) edit existing files there or (ii) create files elsewhere and move them there. (Also, gvim running with administrator access can't create a (new) swap file there).

I created a subfolder ("test"), and took ownership of it, but it made no difference. One of my colleagues thought that this was a "special case" overridden by IIS and could be configured by the Group Policy Editor somehow?

I've heard that disabling UAC solves the problem, but I don't want to do that!

Any ways round this? (Reference to an existing discussion I missed would be fine if it covers the same problem). Thanks!

- Smychi

Answer (score 0):

Solved this; I added the specific administrative user account I was logged in under ("User") to the list of permissions and granted myself "Full Control".

Not sure why this didn't already work with the existing groups settings, though I'll admit my knowledge of Windows permissions isn't as good as it should be.

Feel free to say whether this is a good or bad way to do it, or add any comment to this anyway, for my benefit or for others who might stumble across this.

- Smychi